# Java keytool max pass length

Tags: java, passwords, rsa, keystore, pkcs#12

I want to use this command from Java's keytool to create a keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -alias clientprivate -keystore client.private -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg rsa -storepass password -keypass password
```

Then use the resulting keystore for a java program. But when calling `clientKeyStore.load(loader.clientpublic(), "password".toCharArray());`

I get the error `java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.`

I believe that it's because I used a quite long password of 109 characters. So my question is, what is the maximum allowed password length?

Comment: I don't have any problem with a 109 character password. You problem is caused by something else. How are you getting `clientKeyStore`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the length of your password. It's because the keystore has been corrupted or is otherwise not valid.

Comment: what does `clientKeyStore.getType()` return?

Comment: Are you loading the right file in your `loader.clientpublic()`?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I made a stupid mistake;
I had the certificates all included in a resource package with a resource loader, and the methods clientpublic() clientprivate() serverpublic() and serverprivate().

I was still messing with the resources and I managed to get it to work, but I'd forgotten to set the methods to their respective certificates, they were all pointing to the private client certificate :). Changing that solved the issue.